# Download files from Amazon S3 and rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I am working on a project where I want my users to upload files on Amazon S3 using rails. Although I could upload files on Amazon, I couldn't find any documentation or tutorial on how to retrieve the uploaded files.

Can someone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For uploading and using the uploaded files I highly recommended [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)

Comment: I did use paperclip to upload files on Amazon s3 and it works just fine.  But the thing is I don't know how to access the uploaded files, since my files are not on my local machine but on Amazon s3.

Comment: With paperclip, you can give a public url like @user.avatar.url (for the avatar image) in your forms. If you want to use the image within rails, you can also download it form that url on your server.